# Separated powers and high power switches - alternatives to relays

Tags: arduino, switches, dc-motor, high-current, high-power

I want to use an Arduino (5V, 0-40 milliamps) to control some switches, which in turn control a high current line (12V, 40A,) but the coils in the relays which I use are too heavy for the Arduino to pull off.

The relays don't turn on.

What are my alternatives to relays and separating the low power Arduino from a high power line?

Is there a way to use MOFSETs in regards of separating the power lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the relays which I use use too heavy coils for the arduino to pull off.

If you are connecting relays directly to Arduino output pins you might destroy your Arduino! You can use a power MOS-FET to directly drive the relay coil like this:

[image]
Schematic by [Jeff Sampson](http://www.sampson-jeff.com/tcrobowar/motor1/ver1.htm).

Instead of motor you connect the relay coil.

To separate Arduino from power line, use an optoisolator like this:

[image]
Schematic by [Lewis Loflin](http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele/opto_isolated.htm).

Usually optoisolators are used to separate low from high voltages. They have nothing to do with the current. The MOS-FET handles the current.

There is no need for relays as long as your MOS-FET supports the 40 A current. Just connect the load in series with its drain-source pins.

Comment: I'd mention that if your chip runs at 5V, you can get away without the BJT's - simply relying on the fact that most MOSFET's have a threshold below 5Volts.